# Minimizing The Expected Loss Of a Classification Problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, classification, loss-functions

I found the following squared-loss function for the regression of classification problem:
I learned that the expected loss of any classification problem is given by the following:

$\begin{gather*}
    E[L] = \iint L(t, y(x))\times p(x,t) \,dx\,dt
\\\end{gather*}$

$\text{Where L(t, y(x)) is our loss function and x is our input vector and t is the class label }$
$\text{that x will be assigned to}$

$\text{Now, I also learned that a choice of loss function is the squared-loss where L(t, y(x)) = }$ $(y(x)-t)^2$

$Accordingly,$
$\begin{gather*}
     E[L] = \iint (y(x)-t)^2 \times p(x,t) \,dx\,dt
\\\end{gather*}$

$\text{Since our goal is to minimize the expected loss, we find the derivative of}$
$\text{E[L] with respect to y(x)} \space equal \space to:$

$\frac{\partial E[L]}{\partial y(x)} = 2 \int(y(x)-t) \times p(x,t) dt$

$Setting \frac{\partial E[L]}{\partial y(x)}=0  \text{ means that } y(x) = \frac{\int t p(x,t) \space dt}{p(x)}$

$\text{My questions are: How did we find} \frac{\partial E[L]}{\partial y(x)} \text{ and how did we find the value of y(x) = }$
$\frac{\int t p(x,t) \space dt}{p(x)}$?
As in, what are detailed steps to find both values? I'm asking this because the sources that gave these formulas/functions did not provide the detailed steps, they simply went straight to the final solutions.

Comment: There is some a nice explanation of this in Bishop's Introduction to Pattern Recognition and ML

Comment: I found this from Bishop's textbook and that is what I was referring to as the "source"

Comment: Your first question is answered in the duplicate thread.  The second one is far easier: from linearity of integration, $$0=2\int(y(x)-t)p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t = y(x)\int p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t - \int tp(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$ which immediately leads to the solution $$y(x)=\frac{\int tp(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t}{\int p(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t}.$$ Notice the integral sign in the denominator.  Evidently the notation "$p(x)$" refers to the integral in the denominator.